# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'licenses' (Angular from subfolder)

Tags: angular, iis

I'm having some issues with Angular routing when the angular project is hosted as an application and not as main website.

So the angular application is hosted at `example.it/licenses/` and when i try to go to the following path  i get the following error:

```
main.ed82e0a41cbb59f8be1c.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'licenses'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'licenses'
```

But when the same project is running as main website so not from a subfolder as an application all works fine...

Here is the routing code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LicensesComponent } from './licenses/licenses.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", pathMatch: 'full', component: LicensesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'licenses',
  {path: 'licenses', component: LicensesComponent}
];
```

Your route only contains blank, when you navigate to /licenses, you should add 'licenses' to your routing.

Comment: that was it, i thought as /licenses/ for the IIS was yet the main route that it was enough to set the route to blank in Angular.